# Git Hooks not running automatically

Tags: python, git, hook, chmod

I am trying to setup a git hook so I can integrate with bugTracker.net. They provide a git hook script which I have pasted into the post-commit.sample file for use. I have removed the .sample suffix so the file name is now post-commit. I have installed python and set the path. The hook however is not being automatically ran. It runs successfully if manually ran.

I have given "everybody" "full control" over the file (afaik that is window's version of chmod777)

Can somebody give me some pointers?

Thanks,
Max.

Comment: What Git are you using? The cygwin one? msysgit?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this problem asked a few times over the past week or so by people trying to host a git repo on Windows so right from the start I'm almost certain what the problem is but lets run down the specifics of your setup to see.

What protocol are you using to push with? Are you using SSH, HTTP(S), FTP, RSYNC, or GIT? SSH and HTTPS are really the only two protocols that ever get used for pushing.

I am going to assume that you are using HTTP(S) because that's critical to the common scenario I keep seeing.

How did you setup HTTP(S)? Are you using the older method that is essentially just allowing HTTP(S) access to the repo and putting `git-update-server-info` in one of the hooks (its there in one of the default sample hooks)? Or are you using the newer method that uses [`git-http-backend`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-http-backend.html) as a CGI script?

The assumption that I am making is that you are using the older HTTP(S) method. That method was never really ment for pushing to a repo and doesn't cause the hooks to be executed. You need to switch to the newer method that uses the [`git-http-backend`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-http-backend.html) CGI script or use SSH.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Our origin git repo is http://*networkPcName*/repositories/repo.git so we are using the http protocol. I just copied and pasted the git post-commit hook from the bugtracker.net download into my hooks repo and changed the appropriate settings so could not tell you what it is using. Can you point me in the right direction to learn about moving to a newer push protocol?